# Find duration of file works only for mp4 and not for other formats in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, typescript, html5-video, html5-audio

Hi I want to find the duration of the file before upload to server in client-side through typescript.
I used the below code to find the duration of the file

```
let vd = <HTMLVideoElement>document.querySelector('#getDurationTag'); 
let objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(uploadfile); 
vd.src = objectURL; 
duration = vd.duration;
```

the above code is working fine for files of type .mp4, But not working for other file types and audio type files.
can anyone suggest any other ways to achieve this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: That isn't JS. I think it's TypeScript... (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Yes, This is typescript and I am writing this code in angular4